# jQuery .change() event doesn't fire on select list from keyboard: how can I override this?

Tags: jquery

The jQuery `.change()` event doesn't fire the second time the user types and presses Enter to select an item. It does fire the first time.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/CtXbU/

If you focus on the list and type AD and press Enter, [EDIT] the alert fires. But if you then type AG and press Enter, nothing happens. The alert only pops up when you click away from the list.

What do I do if I want to handle the user changing the list both with the mouse and the keyboard?

I know I can use `.keypress()` to handle keyboard events, but it feels odd to have two separate sections of code both doing the same thing.

Is there a single jQuery event that would handle both mouse and keyboard changes as soon as they occur?

Thanks!

** UPDATE **

This might clarify my question: http://jsfiddle.net/Bybr2/2/

```
// How can I create an event (or handler) that 
// (a) fires AS SOON AS keypress is invoked from user keyboard input
// (b) also fires AS SOON AS change is invoked from user mouse input
// (c) does not fire a second time when change is invoked after keypress, when the user clicks away following keypress?
```

`change` after keypress can be very confusing - it only occurs when the user presses Enter or clicks away, so if I'm making client-side changes then, the user may well be very surprised!

The only solution I can think of is some kind of variable like `user_has_just_done_keypress` which is set as `true` on keypress and then reset to `false` on the next `change` event, but it feels very messy. It also wouldn't work if you had a `change` from the mouse before the `change` from the user refocussing. Argh!

Comment: Typing AD and pressing Enter works for me - using Chrome v9.0. What browser? You can actually apply the behaviour to more than one event at a time: bind('change keypress', function)

Comment: oops, it's a bit more subtle than that, sorry, have edited question - it's actually on the SECOND keyboard input that the problem occurs. The first works as you describe.

Comment: You need to have keypress function for this to work in all browsers.

Comment: Keypress is no good because it doesn't pick up mouse events. I want *one* event that handles both.

Answer (score 4):

Add handler for `keyup` event, not keypress! If you use the same handler for keypress as for change, it does not work well in Firefox for example.

```
$("select").bind('change keyup', select_handler);
```

and handler

```
function select_handler() {
    $(this).val();
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you. And to prevent running the code every time a key is pressed I do something like: `if ($(this).val()!=old_value) { ... }`, where `old_value` is the previous value. So, you only have to run your code when the value changes. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. So the better solution is: on('change keyup',function(){})

Answer (score 2):

You can add `keypress` and have both function call another function doing your actual operation. This way the duplication is not as bad. Actually the enter key fires the event in firefox

Comment: I think my solution is the most bulletproof, although you must check that both events are not fired simultaneously on certain actions, which might result in duplication.

Answer (score 2):

The change function would fire for keyboard entry for:

- Google Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m
- Internet Explorer 9.9.8112.16421

However not for Firefox 10.0.7
(All on Windows 7 Professional, SP1)

Adding:

```
$('select').keypress(function() {
  $(this).change();
});
```

to the $(document).ready-function solved if for me, without breaking it for the other browsers.

The change event would still be triggered only once (in spite of the forced change event from within the keypress handler).

Answer (score 0):

That's how `.change()` works for text inputs. You must focus out for the change to take effect. That is also documented at http://api.jquery.com/change/

The change() Api documentation reads

> ...the event is fired immediately when
>   the user makes a selection with the
>   mouse, but for the other element types
>   the event is deferred until the
>   element loses focus.

**UPDATE**
You can combine both keypress and change in one live function as below

```
$('div').live({
  'change': function() {},
  'keypress': function() {}
})
```

Comment: ah okay, but how can I handle both mouse and keyboard events in the same way?

Comment: @AP257 You must add a `keypress()`. You can't have `change()` and `keypress()` all in one. Both have different purposes.

Comment: @AP257 See updated code above. This is how you can bind both keypress and change in one function

Comment: It doesn't, I'm afraid: I then get the same function executing twice, which is not ideal. I'd like a single event that handled both cases. It may be that this simply doesn't exist in jQuery.

Comment: @AP257 I think you misunderstood the way this work. It will not execute twice. keypress will only execute if you do keypress and change will execute when you do change and not both at the same time. This is the only way it can be done.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the problem is that with user keyboard input, you get keypress and *then* change - so the function you call on each of those gets executed twice. Apologies if I wasn't clear. My edited question may clarify the problem....

Comment: @AP257 You are still getting this wrong. Nothing will execute twice. Let's say you assigned the key ENTER for keypress. When you hit enter, keypress will execute and change will not execute. If you do not hit enter and focus out then only change will execute.

Comment: @Hussein I know this is over a year late, but if you hit tab, won't it execute the keypress for tab and then the change for lose focus?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before when working with IE (all versions, I think).  Change events from the keyboard will only fire when the input loses focus; binding to multiple events was the only way to get the handler working like you expect it to.  You can kill some of the redundancy by defining the handler as a global function, and then setting it as the handler for multiple events:

```
function change_handler()
{
    // ...stuff...
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.whatever').bind('change keypress other_event ...', change_handler);
});
```

Not as clean as I'd like it to be, but it's not that bad, and it works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will not work. You need to have a keypress function so you can tell it to watch for the `e.which = 13` or when any other defined key is pressed. You also don't need $(document).ready for this.